# Find Rational Roots and Factor $x^4 + x^3 - 4x^2 + x + 1$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

Find all rational roots of the polynomial $x^4 + x^3 - 4x^2 + x + 1$. Factor this polynomial into a product of monic irreducible polynomials over the rationals.

I am confused about this question, but isn't the rational root theorem tell us the roots are only $\pm1$?

Comment: "...rational root theorem tell us the roots are only ±1" - nope, it tells us that ±1 are the only *possible* **rational** roots.

Comment: And yes, good observation, you should use the [rational root theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem) to reach MJD's conclusion. Then try $\pm 1$ and see if this yields roots.

Comment: Ahh simple. Thank you.

Comment: Another method other than Andre's answer: divide the whole thing by $x^2$. To factorize $x^2 + 1/x^2 + x + 1/x - 4$, let $u = x+1/x$, and note that $x^2+1/x^2 = u^2 - 2$. Then we need to factorize $u^2 + u - 6$. Factorize this, plug $u = x+1/x$ back in, and factorize again.

Comment: @Sanchez, that looks more like an answer than a comment. :)

Comment: @J.M., it takes some time to write that down in full details, so I am leaving it as a comment instead. If anyone wants to write it down properly please feel free to do so.

Answer (score 5):

The Rational Roots Theorem says there cannot be any rational roots except **possibly** $1$ and $-1$. You will find that $1$ works and $-1$ doesn't.

Divide our polynomial by $x-1$.

You will find that the quotient has $1$ as a root!

Divide again. You will get a quadratic, and you know how to handle quadratics.

Answer (score 3):

\begin{align}
x^4+x^3-4x^2+x+1 & = (x^4 - 2x^2 + 1) + (x^3 - 2x^2 + x) = (x^2-1)^2 + x(x-1)^2\\
& = (x-1)^2 \left( (x+1)^2 + x \right) = (x-1)^2(x^2 + 3x +1)\\
& = (x-1)^2 \left( \left(x+\dfrac32\right)^2 + 1 - \dfrac94\right)\\
& = (x-1)^2 \left( \left(x+\dfrac32\right)^2 - \dfrac54\right) = (x-1)^2 \left( \left(x+\dfrac32\right)^2 - \left(\dfrac{\sqrt5}2 \right)^2\right)\\
& = (x-1)^2 \left(x + \dfrac{3+\sqrt5}2\right) \left(x + \dfrac{3-\sqrt5}2\right)
\end{align}

Comment: I never understood how someone can see how to write the original polynomial as a sum in a helpfull way (like in your first equality). How did you note this ? (+1)

Comment: @Belgi It is hard for me to articulate how I noticed this. It seemed obvious when I did it. But it is hard to put it in words.